# getting the call logs of incoming and outgoing calls in android programmatically

Tags: android, phone-call, calllog

I am making an app in which I want to get the call logs of all incoming, outgoing and missed calls. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please refer the following link:

[Get Android phone call history/log programmatically](http://android2011dev.blogspot.com/2011/08/get-android-phone-call-historylog.html)

If you have issues with the link above, please [click here](https://gist.github.com/kannansuresh/57945c9ee3fc29e04f62dc991449d595).

Comment: “This website/URL has been blocked as per instructions from Department of Telecommunications of India.” Please write some useful code here

Comment: The example in that link is now deprecated. Please check my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49097425/997940

Answer (score 9):

All the answers here are using `managedQuery` which is now deprecated. It should be replaced with `getContext().getContentResolver().query()` method instead, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34329561/997940) and demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33679530/997940).

Here is a short sample code, based on those examples:

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
                CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                CallLog.Calls.DATE
        };
// String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

 Cursor cursor =  mContext.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String name = cursor.getString(0);
    String number = cursor.getString(1);
    String type = cursor.getString(2); // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#TYPE
    String time = cursor.getString(3); // epoch time - https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String
    }
cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me:

```
private void getCallDetails() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Details :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number); // mobile number
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type); // call type
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date); // call date
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate)); 
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }
        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
    managedCursor.close();
    miss_cal.setText(sb);
    Log.e("Agil value --- ", sb.toString());
}
```

**Note:** If you want to get the particular call type, then use the below code. For example, if I want income call alone then command/remove the same code in the switch:

```
case beneath
```

Then, use the below code inside income call case:

```
sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);               
sb.append("\n-----Agil----------------------------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
TextView textView = null;


int callcode;
String callType ;
String phNum;
Date callDate;
String callTypeCode;
String strcallDate;
String callDuration;
String currElement;
static boolean ring = false;
static boolean callReceived = false;


StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_call);


                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

                /* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        null, null, strOrder);

                int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);

                int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

                int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);

                int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

                sb.append("Call Log :");



                if(managedCursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    String phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);

                    String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);

                    String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);

                    Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));

                    String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);

                    String callType = null;

                    int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);

                    switch (callcode) 
                    {
                    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:


                        callType = "Outgoing";



                        //sms.sendTextMessage(phNum, null, "Outgoing msg",  null, null);  


                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:

                        callType = "Incoming";
                        //sms.sendTextMessage(phNum, null, "Incoming msg",  null, null);  


                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:

                        callType = "Missed";
                    //sms.sendTextMessage(phNum, null, "Missed msg",  null, null);  

                        break;
                    }
                    sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNum + " \nCall Type:--- "
                            + callType + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDate
                        + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
                    sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
                }


                managedCursor.close();
            textView.setText(sb);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void getLastNumber() {

       //this help you to get recent call
        Uri contacts = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor managedCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contacts, null, null, 
                       null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC limit 1;");
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        managedCursor.moveToNext();
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        String callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate)).toString();
        int callDuration = managedCursor.getInt(duration);
        managedCursor.close();

        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
       sb.append("Phone Number:--- " + phNumber + " ,Call Date:--- " + callDayTime + " ,Call duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
        Log.d("calllogs", "getLastNumber: "+"Phone Number:--- " + phNumber + " ,Call Date:--- " + callDayTime + " ,Call duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
private void getCallLogWithDuration() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Uri contacts = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor managedCursor = this.getContentResolver().query(contacts, null, null, null, null);
    int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Details :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {

        HashMap rowDataCall = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String mName = managedCursor.getString(name);
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        String callDayTime = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:s").format(new Date(Long.parseLong(callDate)));
        // long timestamp = convertDateToTimestamp(callDayTime);
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }
        sb.append("\nName:--- " + mName + "\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");


    }
    managedCursor.close();
    System.out.println(sb);
    Log.i("CallLog", sb.toString());
}
```