# Deprecated ManagedQuery() issue in getting call logs

Tags: android, deprecated

I have a method in which i am trying to get call logs of a phone. but because of deprecated ManagedQuery() i am not able to get that. Please help how can i modify that to meet my needs.

```
private void getCallDetails() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,       null, null, null);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        sb.append("Call Log :");
        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "OUTGOING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "INCOMING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }

            sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber +
                    " \nCall Type:--- " + dir +
                    " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime +
                    " \nCall duration in sec :--- " +
                    callDuration);
            sb.append("\n----------------------------------");

        }
        managedCursor.close();
        textView.setText(sb);
    }
```

Unfortunately the compiler show me a problem on:

```
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,       null, null, null);
```

Because managedQuery() is deprecated.

How could I rewrite this method without using managedQuery()?

Comment: `but because of deprecated ManagedQuery() i am not able to get that.` so did you read `ManagedQuery` docs? do they say anything about what to use instead of `ManagedQuery` ?

Comment: yes they suggested to use cursorLoader but i didn't find anything how can i access call logs using cursorLoader

Comment: so use the `CursorLoader` read the javadocs, guides, tutorials etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer here..

[LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html)

Thanks everyone for the help!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can replace your `managedQuery` with it :

```
Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do your UI update from the strings accordingly..

```
      String[] details = new String[]{CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                    CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                    CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                    CallLog.Calls._ID};

            Cursor cursor;

            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, details, null, null, CallLog.Calls._ID + " DESC");
            if(cursor.getCount()!=0){
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String number = cursor.getString(0);
                String type=cursor.getString(1);
                String duration=cursor.getString(2);
                String name=cursor.getString(3);
                String id=cursor.getString(4);
                String dir = null;



                switch (Integer.parseInt(type)) {
                    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                        dir = "OUTGOING";
                        break;

                    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                        dir = "INCOMING";
                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                        dir = "MISSED";
                        break;
                }

            }
            cursor.close();
```