# Android: How to execute an action when a call is disconnected

Tags: java, android

I need to display a dialog to the user with the caller's number when the call is disconnected. How can I do this? Will the app have to be open for this or will it run even if the app is closed?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to implement a broadcast receiver.

Check out this example, [Incoming call broadcast receiver](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_Phone_Call_Broadcast_Receiver__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=61&aaid=86)   . Here are a few of the important details below.

Inside your manifest you will need to add these items.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <receiver
        android:name=".CallComplete"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then in your `CallComplete` class:

```
   public class CallComplete extends BroadcastReceiver {
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
      try {

                TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        
                MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
                
                tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
        }

     }

     private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
        
            Log.d("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+phoneNumber);

            // zero state is CALL_STATE_IDLE
            if (state == 0) {

                String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Phone Number Number : "+phoneNumber;
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(pcontext, msg, duration);
                toast.show();

            }
        }
    }
    }
```

If the number is no longer available you may have to store it during the call state 1 state (which is CALL_STATE_RINGING) and store it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a BroadcastReceiver to listen out for the call being disconnected.

This might help you for getting the details of last caller [getting the call logs of incoming and outgoing calls in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480132/getting-the-call-logs-of-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android-programmatically).